# ASP.NET Core Angular PWA - Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Could not load settings for 'MyAppName'

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have developed an application on ASP.NET Core and Angular (with Identity for Authentication along with Roles). Used Visual Studio to generate ASP.NET Core and Angular models and scaffolding.

I added PWA support using Angular commands and now the app is supposed to be a PWA. Using default ngsw service worker. All assetGroups (JS and CSS) are being cached, however, when going offline, the App Shell is not showing and I get error 504 (Internet not working).

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Could not load settings for 'MyAppName'`

And sometimes get error: `Prod mode Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'connect/authorize'`

According to my expectation, the App Shell should have been cached and shown when going offline. What is going wrong. Is there any issue with my configuration?